# how to set dynamic font color in html table row or column values if specific text return in variable dynamically in that row or column in html table

Tags: html, html-table

how to set dynamic font color in html table row or column values if specific text return in variable dynamically in that row or column in html table, Say failed or succeeded return inside variable return output in html

```
            <td style='width:544.5pt;border-top:none;border-left: none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt' valign="top" width="726">
                <p class="MsoNormal" style='margin-bottom:0in;line-height:normal'><span style='mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"; mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-font-kerning: 0pt;mso-ligatures:none'>$Variable</span></p>
            </td>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.